# How can I remove [object Promise] from discord.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js, keyv

I am making a balance system, and I created a give command. Whenever I give someone some money ($10 for example), their balance shows as "$10 [object Promise]". How can I remove "[object Promise]"?

[image: Balance: $100 [object Promise]]

Full command code:

```js
        if (command === 'give') {

            if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('how much are you gonna send?')

            if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send('format: xd give [amount] [@user]')

            const money = args[0];

            const emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('GRAY')
            .setTitle('you gave them the $$')
            .setDescription(`you gave ${message.mentions.users.first().username} the $$$$$$ (` + args[0] + ` to be exact)`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('sent to pokimane');

            message.channel.send(emb);

            const money2 = moneyAmount - args[0];

            if (isNaN(money2)) {
                Number(money2);
            }

            moneydb.set(message.author.id, money2);



                        const uMA = moneydb.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);

                        const money3 = args[0] + uMA;

                        moneydb.set(message.mentions.users.first().id, money3);
        }
```

```js
// keyv connection
const moneydb = new Keyv('mysql://[user and pass]@localhost:3306/money');
```

Even the database has [object promise] at the end

[phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSbf5.png)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czPUO.png)

Comment: `[object Promise]` means you're trying to send an object of a promise

Comment: You'd have to show us the code where that promise comes from before we could offer ideas for how to deal with the promise correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00 There are no promises though...

Comment: Well, apparently none that you're aware of, but clearly there is a promise that somebody tried to turn into a string and that's where the `[object Promise]` comes from.  Can you show ALL the code that is involved in calculating or displaying the balance because somewhere along that line of execution, there was a promise involved.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated it with more information

Comment: My guess is that `moneydb.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);` returns a promise.  What database is `moneydb`?  And, you create the funny string with `[object Promise]` in it here: `const money3 = args[0] + uMA;`.

Comment: The moneydb database is what stores the amount of money the user has. It is a number so it doesn't make a string (I tested it on other commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `moneydb` is a Keyv database as it appears in your question, then this line of code:

```
const uMA = moneydb.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
```

puts a promise into uMA.  You are apparently missing an `await` like this:

```
const uMA = await moneydb.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
```

So, when you do this:

```
 const money3 = args[0] + uMA;
```

And `uMA` is a promise, it tries to make them both into a string and you get the output that contains `[object Promise]`.

FYI, you can see from the Keyv documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keyv) that both `.set()` and `.get()` return promises.